# Thunderbird notifications are not coming

Tags: windows, windows-10, thunderbird, notifications

I have successfully downloaded Mozilla Thunderbird, but I do not receive notification of new mails. I see notification only when I open Thunderbird, which is a little useless.

PS. If the site for this question is not the suitable, would you like to point me the right one?

[image]

Comment: Windows, Linux or macOS? [Edit] your question or add a tag.

Comment: @help-info.de done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your preferences and your working environment. That said - please check your settings in Thunderbird:

[image]

AFAIK - you`ll need to minimise Thunderbird for notifications. This is resulting in:

[image]

For additional notification on *Windows System Notifications* please check following Thunderbird settings:

[image]

and **Manage notifications** of course in Windows 10 too:

[image]

Comment: hello and thanks for the help. i go to notifications and actions to select the application that will notify me. but thunderbird is not in the list.

Comment: I think I have to accept your answer, since I did not found any way to have it closed and be notified. Thanks for your help.